# Was "The Matrix" based on the "Simulacron-3" novel?

Tags: the-matrix

A friend of mine suggested a book called "[Simulacron-3](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/807801.Simulacron_3)" for me to read, before I decided to grab the book I did some research and realized that it has the same premise as "The Matrix" movie. I know Wachowski brothers did use some of [Plato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_cave), [Kant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenomenon), [Descartes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_daemon) work, they also explicitly said that they wanted to do [Ghost In The Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_%28film%29) for real.

Hence my question, did makers of Matrix say explicitly anywhere that their work was also influenced by "Simulacron-3" novel?

Comment: I read S 3 first edition, July,1964 in 1975. A paperback. There is no doubt that that *The Matrix* used the premise, if not the text.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you please add some more evidence than just this; this answer is likely to get downvoted unless you provide a stronger argument!  Thanks

Comment: I vote for N_Soong comment to be move to the appropriate place here :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["The Thirteenth Floor"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139809/)  was directly adapted from Simulacron-3, and the book may have influenced The Matrix and other source material for The Matrix. As far as I know the directors and producers haven't explicitly referenced Simulacron-3 when talking about influences for The Matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I thought that there was heavy reference to the book Simulacra and Simulation.  I had a copy but had a hard time following it due to the translation from French to english.

There was a copy of the book in the movie when Neo gets the disk with the virus on it after being told to follow the white rabbit.

What is interesting is that the writer of S&S, Jean Baudrillard, disagreed with how the Matrix presented his work.

Answer (score 0):

Question:

*"..did makers of Matrix say explicitly anywhere that their work was also influenced by "Simulacron-3" novel?"*

Answer:

No. It's not recorded in any interviews, blogs, online videos, radio, that
can be dug up as proof. Keep digging though, maybe it is yet to come..